# Why is the Brotherhood of Steel attacking me?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Going down the independent questline. I killed Caesar when Benny fled to the Fort, and Mr House shortly after returning to New Vegas. Then I started doing Yes Man's quests to meet and greet the tribes and I'm down to the last one, The Brotherhood of Steel. Unfortunately they seem to be attacking me if I fast travel to Hidden Valley with five or six paladins. I've loaded a save before fast travelling to them but now I need to figure out why, and how I can fix it. They like me, because I've complete The Lonesome Road and picked to avert the missile launch entirely. Help?

Note: I've completed ED-E My Love in favor of the Followers at this point and he's in my party, could that be why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around 1:30 a.m. to 3:00 a.m. around 3-6 brotherhood paladins will **[patrol](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Valley_bunker#Notes)** the area, due to thier strict "isolation" policy, they will shoot you on sight. You can kill them without  loss of karma or BoS reputation, Or just use a stealth boy then fast travel there or just dont fast travel there around 1:30 a.m. to 3:00 a.m. and you'll be fine, the ones in the bunker won't ever shoot you unless you give them a reason. Also I beleive if you have a positive reputation with the BoS the patrols won't shoot you on sight. Also the door to the BoS bunker's lock is very hard, so if you can't get into the bunker because your lockpick skill isn't high enough just pickpocket one key from the patrols that come out at night.

Answer (score 4):

There's no faction impact for doing ED-E's quest line, so that's not your problem.

The problem is hard to pinpoint, since the game's scripts are very complex and there are more than a few bugs.  One important note is that if you tend to wear NCR armor, don't, as the Brotherhood is hostile towards NCR.

There's a couple of reasonably surefire ways of getting into the bunker without violence, though:

- If you can, head to the 188 Trading Post and pick up [Veronica](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Veronica_Santangelo) who is from the bunker and can be relatively easily convinced to take you there.  There's a pretty good chance that she'll be able to get you into the bunker.  If you've done (or are in the process of doing) [her loyalty quest,](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Could_Make_You_Care) though, these paladins might be part of that.  If that's the case, murder away!
- The other option is to get some faction armor for the Brotherhood.  There's some at a few locations, like in the ruins outside Nellis Air Force base or REPCONN Headquarters, both of which are part of [Still in the Dark](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Still_in_the_Dark)

Finally, the quest here is to wipe them out, so if you're strong enough, you just might go ahead and do that.  Alternatively, you can just tell Yes Man that you don't care, in which case you'll skip having to deal with them.

Comment: I'm wearing neutral armor, the Elite Riot Gear from The Lonesome Road to be precise. The only NCR thing I'm wearing is my beret, because it overlaps with the riot gear helmet and I get both bonuses. But that doesn't give me NCR status.

Comment: Appears to have been a bug. I went over to the bunker again and was this time not attacked by Paladins.

Comment: Look at the answer by Commie Ghost, that is the reason you got attacked.

Answer (score 0):

Try equipping NCR armor again and then taking it off (before you enter the bunker)
The Knight will then come to greet you demanding that you hand over all your weapons, armor, etc.. and then you can follow him it.